# Hide IP for Jenkins Embeddable Build Status in a github project

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Embeddable Build Status Plugin for Jenkins in a github project. 
So far, the project is private and the badge is working fine.

However, now I want to make the project public and keep the build status. The issue is that the status badge compromises the IP of my Jenkins server.

Is there any way to keep the status badge in my main README and hide the IP address of the server?

Thanks in advance